# What is the value of the Casimir for "spin-L spinor" representations of $SO(2n)$?

Tags: representation-theory

In his paper "The classical limit of quantum partition functions" [ https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103907536 ], Barry Simon defines "spin-L spinor" representations of $SO(2n)$ (see Appendix 3). One way to construct them is to take $2L$ copies of the spin-$1/2$ spinor representation and to take the subspace over which the Casimir takes its maximal value. Another way to define them is to take the weight to be $L$ times the fundamental weight defined by $h_i=+\frac12$.

In the same appendix of Barry Simon's paper, the following formula is given for the Casimir in the spin-L spinor representation of $SO(2n)$: $C = \binom{2n}{n} L (L+n-1) (2n-1)^{-1}$.
This formula does not make sense to me, as it appears to grow exponentially in $n$, while I would expect only a polynomial in $n$. Also, it does not seem to reproduce the value of $C=n(n-1)/8$ for $L=1/2$, the fundamental spinor representation.

Is there a typo in Barry Simon's paper, or am I misunderstanding something very basic?